# Adding .wav file from resources (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I am trying to add a .wav/.mp3 file to a project. I've added some pictures and they are working well, but I can't add any music. When I type the `Uri` like `new Uri("file.mp3")` and I put the file in the project directory it works, but this code below isn't (but it reads pictures O.o).

```
Uri jezus_uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/jesusrender.png");
Uri devil_uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/devilrender.jpg");

BitmapImage jesus_obraz = new BitmapImage(jezus_uri);
BitmapImage devil_obraz = new BitmapImage(devil_uri);

Uri muzyka = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/plig.wav");

MediaPlayer punch = new MediaPlayer();
punch.Open(muzyka);
punch.Play();
```

Build action is set to Resource of course. There is no error. Music is just not playing.

Comment: What is punch an object of? SoundPlayer?

Comment: Im sorry i forgot.   punch = new MediaPlayer();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** play sounds from a resource in a Media Player. You can only play it from a file. You may want to go with the approach of having your sound file deployed in the project directory and playing the file from the Media Player.

Alternatively, you can use the `SoundPlayer` to play sounds from a resource file.

```
SoundPlayer sndPing = new SoundPlayer(SoundRes.GetType(), "Ping.wav");
sndPing.Play();
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w5b27z4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Could you post any example of usage the SoundPlayer?